# Failed to load the librdkafka native library using Confluent Kafka in XF

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, apache-kafka, xamarin.android, mono

I am trying to use Confluent.Kafka library in Xamarin Forms, which was successfully installed and the Xamarin.Android project builds successfully. If I try to produce a message, I get System.DllNotFoundException: Failed to load the librdkafka native library.
Any possible fix on this?

Thanks

Comment: Mobile applications cannot use Kafka libraries

Comment: @OneCricketeer I see, how do you suggest i go about this? 
thanks

Comment: The common recommendation is to write a REST API that accepts HTTP requests from mobile apps, then events are then forwarded to Kafka from that web app